# Django ajax How would I change my code to use ajax to like posts without refreshing

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to create a like button. Currently I have it so that user's can like/unlike a post on an article. However, whenever they press the button, the page resets and takes them back to the top. I want to use Ajax to fix this. These are my files for the project.

index.py

```
<form action="{% url 'like-article-view' %}" method="POST" class="mb-1">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value={{article.id}}>
<button type="submit" class="ui primary button" name="{{article.id}}" id="like-unlike-btn">

{% if user not in article.liked.all%}
Like
{% else %}
Unlike
{% endif %}
</button>
```

view.py

```
def like_unlike_post(request):
    user = request.user.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_id = request.POST.get('article_id')
        article_obj = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        user_ = CustomUser.objects.get(id = user)

        if user_ in article_obj.liked.all():
            article_obj.liked.remove(user_)
        else:
            article_obj.liked.add(user_)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user_, article_id=article_id )
        if not created:
            if like.value=='Like':
                like.value='Unlike'
            else:
                like.value='Like'
        else:
             like.value='Like'       
        article_obj.save()
        like.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

urls.py (relevant urls)

```
path('', views.indexView, name="index")
path('liked/', views.like_unlike_post, name='like-article-view'),
```

models.py (relevant models)

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='likes')

LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike'),
)

class Like(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How would I implement Ajax in this? I've tried looking for tutorials but not sure how to adapt it my app. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tutorial: [How to Use AJAX with Django](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-use-ajax-with-django/). It walks you through the process of making AJAX requests to Django using Jquery and Vanilla JavaScript.

Here's what you need to do:

```
class LikeArticleView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("id"))
        qs = article.liked.all()

        if request.user in qs:
            return HttpResponse("Already liked the article.")
        else:
            article.loved.add(request.user)
            return HttpResponse("You liked the Article")
```

When you render your article template, set a `data-id={{ article_id }}` on the like button. You can retrieve the article's id using JavaScript when you send it as part of the POST request body. That will allow you to grab the right Article and update the like count.

When you make an AJAX Post request, you need to set the CSRF token header; otherwise, Django will raise an error. The tutorial above covers that.

The endpoint you would submit the POST request too would be:

```
path('liked/', views.like_unlike_post, name='like-article-view'),
```

You can output the like URL as a data attribute, like the id above, and grab it using JS.